# Elastic search getting response in object

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to access elastic search using NEST library.
I want to use Elastic SQL, I am able to execute query from code and getting response.

## Following is my code.

```
public static User GetUserByUserName(string username)
    {
        var client = new ElasticConnectionManager().GetClient("users");
        var query = "SELECT * FROM users where username = 'DummyStudent_6610'";


        var sqlRequest = new QuerySqlRequest();
        sqlRequest.Query = query;
        sqlRequest.Format = "json";


        var response = client.QuerySql(sqlRequest);
        //How to convert to User object?

        return null;
    }
```

Is there any way to auto map response to c# object? 
In above example I want to return "User" class object which should be auto mapped from elastic search.

Answer (score 0):

Not with ES - Nest directly. But your Hits are in Json, so you can use Json tools to create your class from Hits to POJOs.